# Express server not sending response to client (using fetch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, fetch

I'm using `express` for my server side, and i'm making a post request to the server from the client, using `fetch`.

The data that i'm posting to the server are being sent and displayed. The data from the server's response can't be seen anywhere in the client.

Here's my code in the server side:

```
app.post('/info',
ensureAuthenticated, function(req,res){
   console.log(req.body)
   var tryFetch = {myString: 'I am working fetch'};

   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   res.end(JSON.stringify(tryFetch));
})
```

The client side is as follows:

```
fetch("/info", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({
        name : e.target.parentElement.username,
        socketID : e.target.parentElement.socketID,
        id : e.target.parentElement.id,
    })
})
.then( (response) => { 
    console.log(response)
});
```

When i `console.log()` the response, the console displays:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:4000/info", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:4000/info"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: truestatusText: "OK"
headers: Headers
__proto__: Headersbody: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

I don't know what i'm missing here, and cannot send data from the server to the client. Can anyone help me with this please? It will be much appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: What happens when you try this call from Postman?

Comment: @LearningEveryday I tried this from Postman and it returns the json in the body. It also returns one cookie and 6 headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, i finally found out what's wrong with this case.

The problem is not on the server, but on the client and the fetch promise. Actually, what made me think that the problem was on fetch, was when i `console.log(res.body)` and got

```
ReadableStream {locked: false}
locked: false
__proto__: ReadableStream
```

Here's what worked for me. I replaced

```
.then( (response) => { 
    console.log(response)
});
```

with

```
.then(response => response.json())
                .then((body) => {
                     console.log(body);
                });
```

So in conclusion the fetch must look like this:

```
fetch("/info", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },

    //make sure to serialize your JSON body
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name : e.target.parentElement.username,
        socketID : e.target.parentElement.socketID,
        id : e.target.parentElement.id,
    })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then((body) => {
        console.log(body);
});
```

Now the response from the server is displayed when i `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to `res.send` or `res.json` not `res.end`.

`res.end()` is used to quickly end the response without any data.

```
app.post('/info',
ensureAuthenticated, function(req,res){
   console.log(req.body)
   var tryFetch = {myString: 'I am working fetch'};

   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   res.send(JSON.stringify(tryFetch));
})
```

---

**UPDATE**

To return json

```
app.post('/info',
ensureAuthenticated, function(req,res){
   console.log(req.body)
   var tryFetch = {myString: 'I am working fetch'};
   res.json(tryFetch);
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i've also tried this and doesn't change the result. The response is still the same as i mentioned above.

Comment: @we_mor why do you have this line `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`?

Comment: because i want to return json. Do you think it's causing any problem?

Comment: @we_mor yeah, you don't need that line, if you want to return json look at my edit

Comment: This is not working either, the same thing's happening @1baga

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact same issue using axios due to the argument I was using for .then(). The following update worked for me...

```
axios.post(url, userInfo)
            .then((req, res) => {
                console.log('Response:', res)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log("client Error:", error))
```

Instead of .then((req, res)=>{})

Updated to .then((res) => {})

```
axios.post(url, userInfo)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('Response:', res)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log("client Error:", error))
```